# Count Between Dates Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have this kind of excel where data is not really a date but a text based dates like

A1       A2     A3

January  3-9    # of items

I need to get the number of items between dates of January 3-9 I have another sheets which have a column of dates in this format 1/3/2016

I need to count how many items is there in the date range 3-9 but it's text based and I can't do VLOOKUP on it.

It's basically counting number of items weekly.

Here's my excel file
[excel file mirror](http://expirebox.com/download/9b9a05ae3c7eb41bc75b6974d23ee089.html)
[excel file](http://www.filedropper.com/test_26)

Comment: Your data text based or date text based?

Comment: Can you provide a link to sample spreadsheet with data in the format you are describing.

Comment: added my spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant way to do this.. but this works:

=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,">="&--(CONCATENATE(A2," ",LEFT(B2,FIND("-",B2)-1))),Sheet2!A:A,"<="&--(CONCATENATE(A2," ",RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("-",B2)))))

Copy this down, and it will add up ... it has trouble with differing years though, it begins by assuming that everything is in the current year.

Try the attached file:

http://www.filedropper.com/test_32

Comment: It gives me 0 which I think is wrong because on January 3-9 there should be like 5 items

Comment: Hi Math it worked but can you i  year parameter is it possible? if so then how?